# Как создать рабочий JAR файл в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libgdx

Помогите создать рабочий JAR файл моего проекта, сделанного с помощью фреймворка libgdx. Пытался сделать через Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Create JAR from Modules, создался JAR файл, который запускает приложение на 1 секунду с черным экраном и затем закрывается без ошибки.

UPD1: С помощью Gradle создал JAR файл, но он по прежнему не запускает игру, но зато найдена ошибка. Проблема заключалась в том, что все изображения проекта не загружаются из-за "неправильного пути". Они хранятся в папке assets и поэтому загружаю я их через Gdx.files.internal("img_name.png"). Возможно ли, что скомпелированный JAR файл ищет файлы не в том пути?

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, программа закрывается после выполнения.

Попробуйте в командной строке:

```
java -jar jarName.jar
```

Варианты:

1. Укажите полный путь к jar, если вы в другой директории.
2. Укажите полный путь к java компилятору, если не прописана переменная среды `java_home`
3. Укажите при запуске класс с исполняемым main методом, если он не указан был в манифесте при сборке:

   ```
   java -jar jarName.jar -cp package.ClassWithMainMethod
   ```

Comment: Вы пользуетесь libgdx, насколько я знаю, он использует gradle при сборке. Т.е. нормальный способ создания проекта - сконфигурировать проект в libgdx мастере и импортировать через gradle.  Советую вам собирать проект не стандартным сборщиком Intellij IDEA, а gradle. View-Tools Windows - Gradle. И вызвать задачу - build. И тогда скорее всего соберется нормальное декстопное приложение, которое можно запускать обычным кликом без кмд.

Comment: Да, у меня установлен gradle, в проекте используются build.gradle и settings.gradle, но нет кнопки, которую вы описали "View-Tools Windows - Gradle". Может из командной строки можно как-то вызвать build проекта?

Answer (score 0):

Создать можно через консоль.
1. Открываете консоль
2. пишем cd "путь к папке, в которой лежит gradlew (то бишь папка с вашим проектом)" без ковычек
3. Далее gradlew desktop:dist (если хотите под андроид, то gradlew android:dist) 
Созданный файл будет лежать в <Папка с вашим проектом> > desktop > build > lib
Я таким способом всегда собираю без проблем все проекты)